# Will MediaView still show video ads when height is wrap_content?

Tags: android, admob, native-ads, mediaview

I need to set height of my `com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView` to wrap_content, so it nicely [wraps the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098086/google-ads-mediaview-not-correctly-resizing-height-to-wrap-content-when-displayi). **Will video ads will still show**?

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.MediaView
    android:id="@+id/mediaview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[Native ads policies & guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6329638) state that

> For native videos, the main asset MediaView must be at least 120x120dp
>   (Android) or 120x120pts (iOS). Video ads will not serve to
>   implementations with main asset MediaViews smaller than 120dp in any
>   dimension.

When testing I never get any video ad - just images. I would expect video ads to be working with this setup.